# Getting index member with FinancialData[]

Tags: curated-data, finance

How can I use `FinancialData` to get the ticker symbols for a given index? For example suppose I want the tickers for all 500 stocks currently listed on the S&P 500. Can `FinancialData` give me these tickers?

Comment: In general, yes: FinancialData["Frankfurt", "Members"] Having problem with S&P500 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the example [in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html#49952296) shows

```
FinancialData["^GSPC", "Members"]
```

should work, but it unfortunately returns

> `Missing["NotAvailable"]`

A working alternative is to use

```
EntityList[EntityClass["Financial", "SP500"]]
```

instead. However, it has 506 entries and it is unclear when its last update was.

If you prefer the symbols as strings instead of entities, you can use

```
EntityValue[EntityClass["Financial", "SP500"], "Symbol"]
```

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies) says there are 505 of these stocks, contrary to what the index name implies.

Comment: @J.M. based on that list, `EntityList[EntityClass["Financial", "SP500"]]` is not up-to-date.